# how to count row1 from table1/count row1 from table2 returned result is group by day

Tags: sql, oracle, division

I know this, but I know it won't work.

```
select date_decision,
      (select count(*) from table2)/
      (select count(*) from table1)
from dual
group by date_decision
```

Date_decision is from table2, and there is a common row between table1 and table2 which is Case_number

but I can't group when it's a from the dual table. I'm try to get the count in 1 day from table1 divided by the count in 1 day from table2.

table1

```
 Case_number       Date_application
  39123             01-Jan-14
  17724             05-Jan-14
  13455             01-Jan-14
  42314             03-Jan-14
  10485             02-Jan-14
  38762             02-Jan-14
  93974             03-Jan-14
  17388             01-Jan-14
  29384             03-jan-14
  65438             05-Jan-14
  22312             04-Jan-14
```

table2

```
CASE_NUMBER     DATE_DECISION
  39123         01-Jan-14
  17724         05-Jan-14
  13455         01-Jan-14
  42314         03-Jan-14
  10485         02-Jan-14
  38762         02-Jan-14
  93974         03-Jan-14
```

I want the results to be like

```
Date              Ratio
01-JAN-2014       85.84%
02-JAN-2014       75.33%
03-JAN-2014       82.35%
04-JAN-2014       84.93%
...               ...
```

Comment: Much more information please, which table (or tables) does the date come from? is there anything in common between the tables to join them by. Sample data (per table) would be a big help. Consider setting up a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: post your sample data also

Comment: good start, don't stop now, sample data please. Is t1 the 'case' table and t2 a many to one relationship to t1? (remember we know nothing about your data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the ratio of the number of cases in two tables on all dates as follows. It's not  efficient I guess, but it works.

```
SELECT A.Date_application ALLDATES, ( (A.CNT / B.CNT) * 100) || '%' RATIO
  FROM    (  SELECT t1.Date_application, COUNT (*) CNT
               FROM table1 t1
           GROUP BY t1.Date_application) A
       JOIN
          (  SELECT t2.DATE_DECISION, COUNT (*) CNT
               FROM table2 t2
           GROUP BY t2.DATE_DECISION) B
       ON A.Date_application= B.DATE_DECISION
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I've updated the question. Case_number is owned by both tables. Date_decision is owned by table2

Comment: I updated the answer according to your updates in the question.

Comment: Thank you!! what if I want to group the result by weeks?

Comment: You're welcome. Instead of grouping by Date_application directly, you can group by a week version of this date value. Depending on how you want to start the week, you can play with this clause: GROUP BY TRUNC(t1.Date_application)-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(t1.Date_application,'D')). You also need to change your "A.Date_application ALLDATES" in the select part to meet the same condition in GROUP BY. Do the same for the t2.DATE_DECISION. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524643/how-to-group-by-week-of-the-year-dates-or-day-dates-that-start-on-sundays-in-ora

Comment: Thank you!!! it worked!! now how do I find to 7-day weighted moving average on these two counts?

Answer (score 0):

You want to find ratio of number of cases decided to number of cases applied on a particular day?

You can join the two tables on date column, group by date counting the distinct number of cases. Divide the two counts and you have your ratio.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85f8c/1)

```
  SELECT table1.date_application "date",
         COUNT (DISTINCT table1.case_number) cases_applied,
         COUNT (DISTINCT table2.case_number) cases_decided,
            ROUND (
                 COUNT (DISTINCT table2.case_number)
               * 100
               / COUNT (DISTINCT table1.case_number),
               2)
         || '%'
            percentage_cases_decided
    FROM    table1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            table2
         ON table1.date_application = table2.date_decision
GROUP BY table1.date_application
ORDER BY table1.date_application
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85f8c/1/0)**:

```
|                           DATE | CASES_APPLIED | CASES_DECIDED | PERCENTAGE_CASES_DECIDED |
|--------------------------------|---------------|---------------|--------------------------|
| January, 01 2104 00:00:00+0000 |             3 |             2 |                   66.67% |
| January, 02 2104 00:00:00+0000 |             2 |             1 |                      50% |
| January, 03 2104 00:00:00+0000 |             3 |             3 |                     100% |
| January, 04 2104 00:00:00+0000 |             1 |             0 |                       0% |
| January, 05 2104 00:00:00+0000 |             2 |             1 |                      50% |
```